# Query for Realtime Database Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to make a query for my database in Realtime `Firebase`.
It is my database structure:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jMQn.png)

**json:**

```
{
  "Recepts" : [ {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Carrot", "Sugar" ],
    "Name" : "Carrot Salad"
  }, {
    "Ingridients" : [ "Orange", "Milk" ],
    "Name" : "Orange Milk"
  } ]
}
```

How can I do a query, I make code like this:

```
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference resultRef = rootRef.child("Recepts");
Query resultQuery = resultRef.orderByChild("Ingridients");
```

But I can not add `ValueEventListener` for `Query` object.
What do I need to do?

**upd**
How can I structure my database in Firebase for search for recipes? Each recipe have some ingridients. I need to search for recipes.
If the query contains several matching ingredients, Ineed to output a recipe containing a matching value

Comment: Firebase can query the children of a specific location if the property is at a known path in the JSON. As you can see in your screenshot the ingredients are not at a known path, because they may be at any index in the array. That's why arrays are not a good structure to store such a collection of ingredients. Instead consider storing them as a map, which prevents having duplicate ingredients in a recipe. Then also store the inverse data structure, from an ingredient to the recipes that use that ingredient. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40657455

Comment: Don't update a question closed as a duplicate to ask another question; you won't get any answers for it. Ask a new question instead.